# How to I set a user to automatically log in?

Tags: ubuntu-9.04, automatic-logon

I'm setting up a computer running Ubuntu for my mom, so that she will be able to read e-mail, surf the Internet and use Skype. She is the only person accessing the computer.

Is it possible to set it up so that she doesn't have to log in?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Click on System > Administration > Login Window.

   [image: menu]
2. Enter your password.
3. Click on the "Security" tab.
4. Check "Enable Automatic Login".
5. Select your mom's account for "User" in the "Enable Automatic Login" section.

   [image: login preferences]
6. Click "Close".

Comment: Thx so much. I did it and it worked just fine

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what theme is that? :)

Comment: It's the excellent shiki-colors theme, with matching gnome-colors icons. You can find more about the theme, icons, and matching GDM login window here: http://code.google.com/p/gnome-colors. I use the "Wise" (green) variation. If you add the icons, make sure to add both "gnome-colors" Wise and "gnome-colors extras" (extras are the non-green-ified icons)

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is.

Find the `Control Center` in the Menu 
 (If you don't have Control Center, go to System > Administration > Login Window.)

[image: Picture of Control Center]

Select `Login Window`. Under the `Security` tab, check `Enable Automatic Login`.

[image: Picture of Login Window]

Comment: I don't believe the Control Center is included by default in Ubuntu 9.04.

Comment: Should be easy enough to apt-get install it, don't know the exact package name thou...

Comment: Ah, I'm working from Linux Mint. I'll add information for how to get to it without control center

Comment: I searched Add/Remove programs and Synaptic for control center, and couldn't find it. Are you sure it's in the official Ubuntu repositories?

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it without any graphical interface by simply adding the following two lines in the section [daemon] of the file **/etc/gdm/gdm.conf-custom**:

```
...
[daemon]
AutomaticLoginEnable=true
AutomaticLogin=<your user name>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the GUI:

In the system menu, go to login manager. In there, select a user and select "log in automatically". You can also specify how long do you want to wait before logging in as that user.

PS: I am not in front of an Ubuntu machine right now, and I am mostly quoting from memory. So there might be subtle differences.